# Not able to Start Hybris server

Tags: java, sap-commerce-cloud

I am using JDK 11.0.6 version and hybris 1905, I am able to build setup successfully but when I start server I am getting below error

> FATAL  | wrapper  | The argument
>   '1905\hybris\bin\platform\tomcat/conf/wrapper.conf' is not a valid
>   property name-value pair.

What is the reason for this?

Comment: What procedure did you use to setup Hyrbris? Did you follow any guide from Hybris Help site?

Answer (score 3):

In the path, there must be a folder specified with space in the name like: "hybris 1905" so try removing this space. rename it to something like: "hybris_1905" then run ant clean all command and then start the server.

Answer (score 2):

When developers received above error message, they should check complete path. Even folder name should not have any space, else you will get this error message.

For example,
C:\projects\**abc xyz**\hybris\ will give this error.(**Wrong** approach)

C:\projects\**abcxyz**\hybris\ will resolve the issue.(**Correct** approach)

**Note:** While working on Hybris project, we should not give any space for folder/directive name and we should avoid giving long folder/directive name.